# Object doesn't appear using Sprite Renderer when triggered

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a Mario replica in unity for my homework, and I'm trying to make the "Invisible" block, it starts off invisible, then when hit, it turns visible. I'm trying to use SpriteRenderer.enable to make it work, it works for turning it off in the start, but not when trying to make it visible.

I've tried to create a separate script for this particular block, but results are the same. All the tags are set correctly, I've tried using Debug.log to see if I enter the "if" where the sprite should be enabled, but the result is negative.

This is the start method turning off the sprite renderer for the particular block (it works):

```
private void Start()
{
    //rendObject = this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    if (gameObject.tag == "Invisible")
    {
        gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = false;
    }
}
```

This is all the blocks script:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (timesToBeHit > 0)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player" && IsPlayerBelow(collision.gameObject))
        {
            if (gameObject.tag == "Invisible")
            {
                gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = true;
            }
            collision.gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerController>().isJumping = false; //Mario can't jump higher
            Instantiate(prefabToAppear, transform.parent.transform.position, Quaternion.identity); //instantiate other obj
            timesToBeHit--;
            anim.SetTrigger("GotHit"); //hit animation   
        }
    }

    if (timesToBeHit == 0)
    {
        anim.SetBool("EmptyBlock", true); //change sprite in animator
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've found a solution in chat, but for all people who may run or have run on this kind of problem will need to check for the next things:

- Must have 2 Colliders of any type, 1 per gameObject.
- At least 1 Rigidbogy.
- Appropriately Collider setup.
- Appropriate Tags.
- Appropriate Layer Collision Matrix.

The code below will work.

```
public SpriteRenderer render;

void Start()
{
    render.enabled = false;
}

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        render.enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Elvis The script is attached to that gameObject, right? and are you sure that second part of your code is called?

Comment: Yes the script is attached, it does get to the first `if` but it doesn't get to the `if (gameObject.tag == "Invisible")` part, even tho the tags are correct

Comment: Can you tell me why do you need a checker for Invisible?

Comment: You mean this `if (gameObject.tag == "Invisible")` ? Because the script is for all the blocks that are in the game, I'm trying to check if the tag is "Invisible" of the block, and if it is, turn the sprite on. I even created a separate script, but the results are still the same

Comment: @Elvis Does it enter when the gameObject is Invisible or it skips, can you check this?

Comment: If I add a `Debug.Log("Object should turn visible");` in `if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")` it doesn't show anything, means this part doesn't trigger, but the tags are 100% correct

Comment: Then you forgot to add Tag to gameObject, no other reason.

Comment: Block inspector: http://prntscr.com/nbhzj1 
Player inspector: http://prntscr.com/nbi0a2

Tags are set correctly, yet it doesn't work... Maybe I could send You the whole project (it's small, 20mb) and You could check it out, if You have time to spare ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class InvisibleBlock : MonoBehaviour
{
    public SpriteRenderer rendObject;

    private void Start()
    {

        if (gameObject.tag == "Invisible")
        {
            rendObject.enabled = false;
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            rendObject.enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Separate script, sprite is attached in inspector, same results.