# Player don't die when bullet touches him

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

[image]

My player does not die when they are hit with bullets from my tank. I think the problem is in the `OnTriggerEnter2d` method. The bullet goes through the player without killing them.

```csharp
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour
{
    float moveSpeed = 7f;
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    Player target;
    Vector2 moveDirection;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        target = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<Player>();
        moveDirection = (target.transform.position - transform.position).normalized * moveSpeed;
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveDirection.x, moveDirection.y);
        Destroy(gameObject, 3f);  
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D ( Collider2D col)
    {
        if(col.gameObject.name.Equals ("Player"))
        {
            Debug.Log("Hit");
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing in your code even attempts to destroy or otherwise damage the player

Comment: void OnTriggerEnter2D ( Collider2D col)
    {
        if(col.gameObject.name.Equals ("Player"))
        {
            Debug.Log("Hit");
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

Comment: @isaa You should check everything that may have impact on this action, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55667608/object-doesnt-appear-using-sprite-renderer-when-triggered/55667795#55667795). Btw.. skip checking tags, your using gameObject name.

Comment: `Destroy(gameObject);` destroys the bullet.

Comment: There's no trouble with the code. If the bullet goes through, the problem must be at Collision Matrix or Collider setup.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are destroying the bullet and not the player. Try destroying the gameObject that belongs to the player collider instead:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D ( Collider2D col)
{
    if(col.gameObject.name.Equals ("Player"))
    {
        Debug.Log("Hit");
        Destroy(col.gameObject);
    }
}
```

When you say `Destroy(gameObject)`, `gameObject` by itself refers to the GameObject that this component is attached to.  Its the same as saying `this.gameObject`. Since you named the component bullet, I'm guessing this script is attached to a Bullet object, and thus your player will not be destroyed.

See: [Component.gameObject](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component-gameObject.html)